# CheckedListBox checkedItems

Tags: c#, datagridview, checkedlistbox

How can I get an access to the checkedItem of a checkedListBox?

For example I have checkedListox of 3 items:

1. None;
2. All;
3. Unique.

And after I'm working with a dataGridView displaying different data depends on the checkedListBox checkedItems.

So if "none" item checked - nothing displays, if "All" item checked - displays all data and if "Unique" item checked - displayn only unque values.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the CheckedListBox' `SelectionMode` to `SelectionMode.One` to ensure that only one of the options can be chosen at a time.

Then, subscribe to the CheckedListBox' `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event to get notified when the selection changes, in there read its `SelectedIndex` oder `SelectedItem` property to find out which option has been chosen, and change the DataGrid's content accordingly...